# Check if object has multiple values based off array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

**Solution**

Sergio's answer below worked great, specifically the *objectsMatch* function he provided. I also need to support **multi-select** select elements for filtering so I modified his function a bit, here it is in case anyone else is looking for similar functionality:

```
function objectsMatch(roll, filterObject) {
  var match = true;
  for (var prop in filterObject) {
    if(!roll.hasOwnProperty(prop) ||
       !filterObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
       if(Array.isArray(filterObject[prop])){
         var matchesNoValues = function(){
           for(var i = 0; i < filterObject[prop].length; i++){
             console.log(filterObject[prop][i])
             if(roll[prop] == filterObject[prop][i]){
               return false;
             }
           }
           return true;
         }
           if (matchesNoValues()  &&
                filterObject[prop] != ''
               ) {
               match = false;
               }
       }else{
         if (roll[prop] != filterObject[prop]  &&
                filterObject[prop] != ''
             ) {
             match = false;
             }
       }
    }
  return match;
}
```

**EDIT 1**

I was able to replicate the functionality I'm looking for in an MVP [here](https://jsfiddle.net/adrian_r/402wer3h/). And am now trying to figure out how to apply that to my filter. Hopefully this can better demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve.

**Original Post**

I am attempting to add a custom filter for filtering rows in a table in Angular. I need to check whether each object in my repeat has **all** the values represented in my filters array. These values are set by **select** elements in my table.

For example, my data set looks like:

```
$scope.sushi = [
  { name: 'Cali Roll', fish: 'Crab', tastiness: 2 },
  { name: 'Philly', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 4 },
  { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Eel', tastiness: 7 },
  { name: 'Tiger', fish: 'Tuna', tastiness: 3 },
  { name: 'Rainbow', fish: 'Variety', tastiness: 62 }
];
```

And say my filters array contains:

```
var filters = ['Philly', 'Tuna', 4];
```

it will only show

```
$scope.sushi[1]
```

in the repeat.

Then say the filters array values are updated to:

```
var filters = ['Philly', 'Tuna', 1000];
```

Now no rows would display because there is no object in my dataset that contains **all** the values in the filters array.

[HERE](https://jsbin.com/geriseyoxe/edit?html,js,output) is a link to what I've tried so far, with both methods marked *METHOD 1* and *METHOD 2*, respectively.

I think I'm almost there with *METHOD 1*, but if I select multiple values that **are** in the object, no rows get displayed, it only displays a row when I only select **1** filter. As for *METHOD 2*, its only checking that at least one of the values in the filters array are in the object, not all.

Here is the full code in my filter:

```
.filter('byColumn', function(){
  return function(rolls, filterVal){
  var filtered = [];
  var test = true;
  for(var x in rolls){
    var currentRoll = rolls[x];
    for(y in currentRoll){

    // METHOD 1
    var allMatches = true;
    for(var i = 0; i < filterVal.length; i++){
      if(filterVal[i]){
        if(currentRoll[y] == filterVal[i]){
          continue;
        }else{
          allMatches = false;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    if(allMatches){
        if (filtered.indexOf(currentRoll) == -1) {
          filtered.push(currentRoll);
        }
    }
    if(!allMatches){
      rolls = [];
    }

    // METHOD 2
    // angular.forEach(filterVal, function(filter){
    //   if(currentRoll[y] == filter){
    //     if (filtered.indexOf(currentRoll) == -1) {
    //         filtered.push(currentRoll);
    //     }
    //   }
    // });

      }
    }
        return filtered.length ? filtered : rolls;
      }
    });
```

The code is based off a tutorial by Scotch.io found [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular) that I have modified to fit my needs.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass to the **byColumn** filter the **columnFilter** object instead of the **filters** array

will look like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="roll in sushi | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:searchFish | byColumn:columnFilter track by $index">
  <td>{{ roll.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ roll.fish }}</td>
  <td>{{ roll.tastiness }}</td>
</tr>
```

**byColumn** filter could look like this:

```
.filter('byColumn', function(){
    return function(rolls, filterVal){

   var filtered = [];

   for(var x in rolls){
      var currentRoll = rolls[x];

      if(objectsMatch(currentRoll, filterObject)) {
          filtered.push(currentRoll);
      }
   }

   return filtered;
  };
})
```

And this is the **objectsMatch** function

```
function objectsMatch(roll, filterObject) {

    var match = true;

    for (var prop in filterObject) {

        if(!roll.hasOwnProperty(prop) ||
           !filterObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;

        if (roll[prop] != filterObject[prop] && filterObject[prop] != '') 
        {
            match = false;
        }
    }

    return match;
}
```

Fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wsve2zwf/2/)

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks for taking a look @Sergio, but it doesn't seem like the fiddle is working? As soon as I make a selection all the rows disappear?

Comment: I thought that was the desired behavior. Only rows that match the three filters will be shown

Comment: Sorry I guess I wasn't clear in my initial post. What I am looking for is if there is a filter, it only shows rows that contain that value. If there are 2 filters in the array, it only shows rows that have BOTH those values. If there are 3 filters in the array, it must contain all 3 values in that row, etc. I added a link to an MVP fiddle that better demonstrates what I'm looking for

Comment: @adrian_reimer I updated the answer. Hope it helps now